# First started Kafka server & leader failure blocks consumers

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm basically doing the kafka [quickstart](https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart) using [kafka_2.11-2.0.0](http://mirrors.hostingromania.ro/apache.org/kafka/2.0.0/kafka_2.11-2.0.0.tgz) which comes with `zookeeper.version=3.4.13-2d71af4dbe22557fda74f9a9b4309b15a7487f03, built on 06/29/2018 00:39 GMT`.
I also use Ubuntu:

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

I do these with the order below:

- start zookeeper
- start kafka server0 with port 9092
- start kafka server1 with port 9093
- start kafka server2 with port 9094
- create a topic: `kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 3 --partitions 1 --topic my-replicated-topic`
- produce some messages: `kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic my-replicated-topic`
- consume from server0: `kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --from-beginning --topic my-replicated-topic`
- consume from server1: `kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9093 --from-beginning --topic my-replicated-topic`
- check the leader for *my-replicated-topic* and find it to be server0 -> here's the tricky part; one should kill server1 and then maybe server2 but never server0 and then restore them just in order to get server0 to be the leader of *my-replicated-topic*
- kill server0
- check for the new leader (happens to be server2): `kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic my-replicated-topic`
- produce some messages to server2: `kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9094 --topic my-replicated-topic`
- consume from server2 (or server1): `kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9094 --from-beginning --topic my-replicated-topic` -> **this will hang till restarting server0**
- starting again server0
- consumer from server2 outputs all messages including the one sent to server2 when was the leader

What is wrong and how one would solve the problem so not to matter which server becomes the leader?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is due to replication factor of "__consumer_offsets" topic.  This is set to one in server.properties file for testing purpose.
set offsets.topic.replication.factor=3 for high availability.

Copied from [KAFKA-7526 comment](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7256?focusedCommentId=16573637&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-16573637)

Comment: PS: I changed the question by adding an additional related one.